# Create dropdown list in jade and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pug

So what I would like to do is loop through an array I pass in when rendering the editRoom page and display the rooms in a dropdown menu.

I want to be able to highlight a room from the menu then use req.body to access the highlighted field. From here I know how to load a new page etc...

I don't know how to make a dropdown menu, I got this code from another question on here but can't seem to make it work. I don't even know if this will give me what I want.

editRoom.jade:

```
extends layout

block header
  script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='js/bootstrap.min.js') 
  script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js')

block content
  form(method="post", action="/edit")
    div(class="dropdown")
      button(class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only", type="button" id="dropdownMenu1", data-toggle="dropdown")
        Dropdown
        span(class="caret")
      ul(class="dropdown-menu", role="menu", aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1")
        li(role="presentation") a(role="menuitem", tabindex="-1", href="#") Action
        li(role="presentation") a(role="menuitem", tabindex="-1", href="#") Another action
        li(role="presentation", class="divider")
        li(role="presentation") a(role="menuitem", tabindex="-1", href="#") Separated link
      script.
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
  button(type="submit") Submit
```

I get a link to a dropdown menu but it doesn't lead anywhere.

Thank you!